# Oracle database 12c "compress for query" OPTION

Tags: oracle, compression, exadata

I have a development server on a simple server with oracle 12c and our production server is on Oracle Exadata.

On some of the tables we use COMPRESS FOR QUERY option.
My problem is every time we create a table we need to remove this option(from DDL) for development and put it when we deploy changes on production.

Is there any option at database level to use the option on development server also, even if the server is not exadata(something like skiping it) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Define compression at the tablespace level, then when you create your tables in development, don't include any of the storage elements, just let their TABLESPACE characteristics take affect.

Barring that, you're going to have two sets of DDL scripts for source control, one for development, and another for production.

Comment: Thank you, but i want only one set of scripts.
And on my development database to change on parameter, something like that: alter database set FAKE_COMPRESSION_PARRAMETER = TRUE
Exists something similar ?

Comment: your ddl scripts could be uniform across the the two environments, if the tablespace names are the same, just build the compression details into the tablespace settings, NOT at the table level